Spring Boot Microservices: 'Service Unavailable' Error when Accessing Endpoint via API Gateway
I'm working on a Spring Boot microservices application and have dockerized all the services. While all the services appear to be running, I'm encountering an issue when trying to access the endpoints via the API Gateway.
Error Message:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-06-24T14:01:32.938+00:00",
    "path": "/departments",
    "status": 503,
    "error": "Service Unavailable",
    "requestId": "1a88ca39-1"
}

Problem Description:
The Eureka server (service-registry) only registers the API Gateway and not the other services (department-service, employee-service, and project-service). This makes me think that the API Gateway can't find the services, or the services are not set up correctly to fetch the configuration from the config-server which is other independent service.
Configuration Files:
Service Registry (Eureka) Config:
server:
  port: 8761

spring:
  application:
    name: service-registry

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://service-registry:8761/eureka/

API Gateway Config:
server:
  port: 8060

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://service-registry:8761/eureka/

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: employee-service
          uri: lb://employee-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/employees/**
        - id: department-service
          uri: lb://department-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/departments/**
        - id: project-service
          uri: lb://project-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/projects/**

Department Config:
spring:
  application:
    name: department-service

  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:http://config-server:8088"

Employee and Project Config is just same with department just different app name:
Config Server Config:
server:
  port: 8088

spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/config

Config Server Department Config:
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://service-registry:8761/eureka/

spring:
  application:
    name: department-service
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/microservice_comp_data
    username: postgres
    password: password
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

server:
  error:
    include-message: always
  port: 8081


management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0

Config Server Employee and Project is just same with department just different app name:
Docker Compose:
version: '3.8'
services:
  config-server:
    build:
      context: ./config-server
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"

  service-registry:
    build:
      context: ./service-registry
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    depends_on:
      - config-server

  department-service:
    build:
      context: ./department-service
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/microservice_comp_data
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - service-registry
      - postgres

  employee-service:
    build:
      context: ./employee-service
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/microservice_comp_data
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - department-service

  project-service:
    build:
      context: ./project-service
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/microservice_comp_data
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - employee-service

  api-gateway:
    build:
      context: ./api-gateway
    ports:
      - "8060:8060"
    depends_on:
      - service-registry

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: microservice_comp_data
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"

  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"

I've double-checked the configurations and logs, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue. Any guidance on what might be wrong or how to properly configure these microservices would be greatly appreciated.

1.ensure your service register success
2.try other route way
3. check if the docker port mapping is sucessful
